# Changing the icon of ErrorProvider gives exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, .net-4.8, errorprovider

I am trying to change the icon of errorProvider in Windowsform. I have added .ico files in Properties->Resources folder. I have tried directly copy pasting the .ico file, have also used the Add resources->Add Existing Files option. What ever I do, if I add my own .ico file and try to set them as errorProvider icon as show in the code below, I get an exception while running the program (particularly when trying to demonstrate the the errorProvider feature in my program). My code is:

```
 private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
            {
                textBox1.Focus();
                errorProvider1.Icon = Properties.Resources.cross; //here I have change the default icon
                errorProvider1.SetError(this.textBox1, "Input UserId"); //having exception in this line
            }
            else
            {
                errorProvider1.Icon = Properties.Resources.right;
            }
        }
```

[image]

The exception details:

```
System.StackOverflowException
  HResult=0x800703E9
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

Comment: Try showing the icon directly, independently of the error provide to eliminate the cause it is icon which is not found. Also add the exception details you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have seen one of my teacher changing the errorProvider Icon in his computer, and it worked well(I used the same method though). I will edit my post with the exception detail. Thanks again

Comment: Why are you trying to change the icon in the first place? That icon is meant to highlight boxes with errors and is displayed when validation fails. Typically validation occurs when you submit a form but you can also trigger it when a control loses focus. Is that what you tried to do by handling `Leave`?

Comment: As for the exception itself, it's typically raised when your code results in infinite recursion. Perhaps your code is triggering `Leave` over and over again

Comment: Or are you trying to use the ErrorProvider as a general purpose status UI? It's not. The name says it all - it's an ErrorProvider.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I am trying to build simple a Log In form . There I am using errorProvider so that if user leaves a textBox(i.e. user name) unfilled this error provider will warn the user. I have seen one of my teacher to change the error provider icon and set a .ico file. If I do not use the .ico file everything is ok. the program is working fine but only when I set the errorProvider this exception pops up.

Comment: I have made an answer. If you don't mind, you could click '✔' to mark my reply as the accepted answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: @JialeXue-MSFT thanks a lot. yours solution really helped me

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what they use the error provider for is not the point.  You should be able to provide a different icon.  This is definitely a .NET 5 bug; I'm also experiencing it.  Use the default icon, it works fine.  Change the icon in the designer, throws SOE.

Comment: @rory.ap .NET 5 is .NET *Core* 5, while this is a .NET Framework question, where customization always worked and were thoroughly documented since .NET Framework 1.0. It's even part of the cert exams.. And yes, misuse is the point - quite often problems are caused by misusing a technology, or trying things at random without actually checking the docs.

Comment: @rory.ap if you have a problem in .NET 5 - don't use .NET 5. It reaches EOL in 1 month. That means no fixes at all. The Long Term Support release is .NET 6. That's not a sudden change, it was announced several years ago when .NET Core 3 came out. You should post a new question. Have you tried using WinForms and custom error icons in .NET 6? Did you add them as resources? Is the error provider documented in .NET 6?

Comment: @rory.ap I just tested this with .NET 6 and got no errors. As the accepted answer explains, the problem was caused by the icon itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding resources through `Resource.resx` can also refer to ico very well. `Copy if new` is another calling method.

Add existing resources：

[image]

It might be better to change the `leave` event to the `Validating` event.

I have tested your code itself and there is no problem.

I have `reproduced the error` here because it is caused by the `ico file itself`.

**It can be solved by changing a picture.**

[The error document is here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stackoverflowexception?view=net-6.0)

```
private void TextBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e) {
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)) {
            textBox1.Focus();
            errorProvider1.Icon=Properties.Resources.error__3_; //here I have change the default icon
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Input UserId"); //having exception in this line
        } else {
            errorProvider1.Icon=Properties.Resources.yes1;
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

You can use a file converter to convert to ico.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! your solution worked. Can you please tell me why it is better to use Validating rather than leaving?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

double click on Resources.resx in your solution explorer then select resource type and click on Add Resource -> Add Existing file

Answer (score -1):

first add ur ico file to resource and set the "Copy to Output Directory" to copy always

[Copy to Outpot Directory Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYK7u.jpg)

```
 private void textBox1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Trim() == "") 
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "ERROR WARNING");
            errorProvider1.Icon = new Icon(@"Resources\termicon.ico");
        }
            
        
    
    }
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxBUs.png)

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie. How can I set the "Copy to Output Directory" to copy always.

Comment: The important change here is the use of the `Validating` event instead of `Leave`, not `Copy to Output Directory`. The error doesn't complain about a missing file. Resources aren't copied to the output either, they're part of the executable itself

Comment: Added image to answer u can check on that.

Comment: The error of op is not the problem of picture call

Comment: @BuğraDemirtaş thanks for the pic. I have tried all the steps you have suggested. but now I get a new exception: 
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Mahin\Desktop\Nov21\LogInForm\bin\Debug\Resourcess\cross.ico'.'

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks a lot. But I have used Validating instead of Leave. But the problem remains the same.